# Why is checking isinstance(something, Mapping) so slow?

Tags: python, python-internals

I recently compared the performance of `collections.Counter` to `sorted` for comparison checks (if some iterable contains the same elements with the same amount) and while the big-iterable performance of `Counter` is generally better than `sorted` it's much slower for short iterables.

Using `line_profiler` the bottleneck seems to be the `isinstance(iterable, collections.Mapping)`-check in `Counter.update`:

```
%load_ext line_profiler  # IPython
lst = list(range(1000))
%lprun -f Counter.update Counter(lst)
```

gives me:

```
Timer unit: 5.58547e-07 s

Total time: 0.000244643 s
File: ...\lib\collections\__init__.py
Function: update at line 581

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   581                                               def update(*args, **kwds):
   601         1            8      8.0      1.8          if not args:
   602                                                       raise TypeError("descriptor 'update' of 'Counter' object "
   603                                                                       "needs an argument")
   604         1           12     12.0      2.7          self, *args = args
   605         1            6      6.0      1.4          if len(args) > 1:
   606                                                       raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
   607         1            5      5.0      1.1          iterable = args[0] if args else None
   608         1            4      4.0      0.9          if iterable is not None:
   609         1           72     72.0     16.4              if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):
   610                                                           if self:
   611                                                               self_get = self.get
   612                                                               for elem, count in iterable.items():
   613                                                                   self[elem] = count + self_get(elem, 0)
   614                                                           else:
   615                                                               super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
   616                                                       else:
   617         1          326    326.0     74.4                  _count_elements(self, iterable)
   618         1            5      5.0      1.1          if kwds:
   619                                                       self.update(kwds)
```

So even for length 1000 iterables it takes more than 15% of the time. For even shorter iterables (for example 20 items it increases to 60%).

I first thought it has something to do with how `collections.Mapping` uses `__subclasshook__` but that method isn't called after the first `isinstance`-check anymore. So why is checking `isinstance(iterable, Mapping)` so slow?

Comment: So your question really boils down to why `isinstance` checks against abstract base classes are slow? Because I don't think this is iterable and `Mapping` specific.

Comment: @Mitch maybe, indeed it seems like the other `collections.abc` classes are equivally slow in `isinstance` checks. Do you know what makes these checks with abc's so slow? :)

Comment: I'm looking into `__instancecheck__`'s implementation now, and it doesn't seem like there's anything too funky that happens - performance is worse when you miss the cache. Going to give it some more thought.

Comment: `isinstance` with an `ABCMeta` class is a Python level operation, unfortunately. There's many checks going on down there in `ABCMeta.__instancecheck__` and passing anything other than a mapping will take the slowest path available.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The performance is really just tied to a collection of checks in [ABCMeta's `__instancecheck__`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/abc.py), which is called by [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

The bottom line is that the poor performance witnessed here isn't a result of some missing optimization, but rather just a result of `isinstance` with abstract base classes being a Python-level operation, as mentioned by Jim. Positive and negative results are cached, but even with cached results you're looking at a few microseconds per loop simply to traverse the conditionals in the `__instancecheck__` method of the ABCMeta class.

---

#### An example

Consider some different empty structures.

```
>>> d = dict; l = list(); s = pd.Series()

>>> %timeit isinstance(d, collections.abc.Mapping)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 µs per loop

>>> %timeit isinstance(l, collections.abc.Mapping)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.16 µs per loop # caching happening

>>> %timeit isinstance(s, collections.abc.Mapping)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.26 µs per loop # caching happening
```

We can see the performance discrepancy - what accounts for it?

**For a dict**

```
>>> %lprun -f abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__ isinstance(dict(), collections.abc.Mapping)
Timer unit: 6.84247e-07 s
Total time: 1.71062e-05 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   178                                               def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
   179                                                   """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
   180                                                   # Inline the cache checking
   181         1            7      7.0     28.0          subclass = instance.__class__
   182         1           16     16.0     64.0          if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
   183         1            2      2.0      8.0              return True
   184                                                   subtype = type(instance)
   185                                                   if subtype is subclass:
   186                                                       if (cls._abc_negative_cache_version ==
   187                                                           ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter and
   188                                                           subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache):
   189                                                           return False
   190                                                       # Fall back to the subclass check.
   191                                                       return cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)
   192                                                   return any(cls.__subclasscheck__(c) for c in {subclass, subtype})
```

**For a list**

```
>>> %lprun -f abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__ isinstance(list(), collections.abc.Mapping)
Timer unit: 6.84247e-07 s
Total time: 3.07911e-05 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   178                                               def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
   179                                                   """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
   180                                                   # Inline the cache checking
   181         1            7      7.0     15.6          subclass = instance.__class__
   182         1           17     17.0     37.8          if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
   183                                                       return True
   184         1            2      2.0      4.4          subtype = type(instance)
   185         1            2      2.0      4.4          if subtype is subclass:
   186         1            3      3.0      6.7              if (cls._abc_negative_cache_version ==
   187         1            2      2.0      4.4                  ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter and
   188         1           10     10.0     22.2                  subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache):
   189         1            2      2.0      4.4                  return False
   190                                                       # Fall back to the subclass check.
   191                                                       return cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)
   192                                                   return any(cls.__subclasscheck__(c) for c in {subclass, subtype})
```

We can see that for a dict, the Mapping abstract classes' `_abc_cache`

```
>>> list(collections.abc.Mapping._abc_cache)
[dict]
```

includes our dict, and so the check short-circuits early. For a list evidently the positive cache won't be hit, however the Mapping's `_abc_negative_cache` contains the list type

```
>>> list(collections.abc.Mapping._abc_negative_cache)
[type,
 list,
 generator,
 pandas.core.series.Series,
 itertools.chain,
 int,
 map]
```

as well as now the pd.Series type, as a result of calling `isinstance` more than once with `%timeit`. In the case that we don't hit the negative cache (like the first iteration for a Series), Python resorts to the regular subclass check with

```
cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)
```

which can be *far* slower, resorting to the subclass hook and recursive subclass checks [seen here](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/abc.py), then caches the result for subsequent speedups.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but I tried running `%lprun -f abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__ isinstance(list(), collections.abc.Mapping)` in the Python console and it doesn't work... how do you make it display that thing with the time for each line of code?

Comment: @dtgq That `%lprun` is from the [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) tool, and you have to load it into your IPython extensions as mentioned in the link.